# 'Image1' is not declared. It may not be accessible due to it's permission level error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql, ms-access, ado.net

I have a comments box which has a template field which looks something like this..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="CommentsDataSource" Height="167px" Width="325px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="background-color:Silver">
                    <div class="avatar-frame">
                        <asp:Image ID="ProfilePic" runat="server"/>
                    </div>
                    <h1><%# Eval("TagLine")%></h1>
                    <h2><%# Eval("IfNonMemberUserName")%></h2>
                    <p><%# Eval("CommentBody")%></p>
                 </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <div style="background-color:White">
                    <div class="avatar-frame">
                    </div>
                    <h1><%# Eval("TagLine")%></h1>
                    <h2><%# Eval("IfNonMemberUserName")%></h2>
                    <p><%# Eval("CommentBody")%></p>
                </div>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CommentsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookMeetConnString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookMeetConnString.ProviderName %>"  SelectCommand="SELECT [IfNonMemberUserName], [UserAvatar], [TagLine], [CommentBody] FROM [comments] WHERE ([BookID] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Some background:**
I have an MS Access database with a table called 'userprofiles' which has a field called AvatarURL. Similiarly there is also a table called 'comments' which has lookupfield called 'UserAvatar' inside of it referring to the 'userprofiles' table's 'AvatarURL' field.

I am receiving the "'ProfilePic' is not declared. It may not be accessible due to it's permission level" error in my code behind. Intellisense is telling me that the image that has the ID 'ProfilePic' is not declared (within the DisplayData sub routine.

The problematic bit of code is:

```
Protected Sub DisplayData()
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofiles WHERE TravellerName=@f1"
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", User.Identity.Name)
    conn.Open()
    Dim profileDr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    profileDr.Read()
    If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("AvatarURL")) Then ProfilePic.ImageUrl = profileDr.Item("AvatarURL")
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

At runtime, detail.aspx works fine, but the avatars in the comment box don't show up at all. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

I have managed to get this far:

> ```
>     Protected Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
>     Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofiles WHERE TravellerName=@f1"
>     Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", User.Identity.Name)
>     conn.Open()
>     Dim profileDr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
>     profileDr.Read()
>     Dim ProfilePic
>     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
>         ProfilePic = e.Row.FindControl("ProfilePic")
>         If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("AvatarURL")) Then ProfilePic.ImageUrl = profileDr.Item("AvatarURL")
>     End If
>     conn.Close()
>
> End Sub
> ```

However, the images still do not appear at runtime. What is wrong with this? Should I be using the datareader?

Comment: Please pare down the code example to the bare essentials of the question. I can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: okay, i've cut the code behind down. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to refer to get at `ProfilePic` is to set it at DataBind time. You'll need to wire up the GridView2_RowDataBound event by adding `OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound"` to your `asp:GridView` tag.

You'll then get the `RowDataBound` event for each row (even header and footer rows, so you need to test for what type of row is currently firing the event. You can then use `FindControl` on the current row item to look for the current row's `ProfilePic`. You'll have to cast the output of that function into an `Image`.

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image ProfilePic = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("ProfilePic");
        ProfilePic.ImageUrl = "stuff";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I understand the logic - its quite simple really. I am having problems with your code above unfortunately though; it says 'End of Statement' expected. Sorry couldn't fix this myself, I am just a beginner!

Comment: @adaam Fixed. Had an extra parenthesis.

Comment: thank you very much, i will see if this works tomorrow when i wake up

Comment: I am still receiving errors. See this screenshot: http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk/Capture.png. Am I just being stupid?

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect the updated code, including the OleDb connection to my ms access database. Unfortunately the images still do not appear?

Comment: Nevermind, I have figured out what was the problem - it was to do with the relative path url of the image in the database to the current folder. Cheers for the help! Please have a look over my updated code though to see if there is anything wrong with it. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

As a control within a *template*, you can only access the control when binding, in particular in the `OnRowDataBound` event handler (for a `GridView`).

In this event handler you need to call `FindControl` with the `ID` of the wanted control and cast it to the right type (only if you need to access specific members of that type).

Comment: Could you possibly specify a code example. Non of the other answers have met my requirements!

Comment: @adaam - [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15722895/1583) by [Lynn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/656243/lynn-crumbling) is essentially what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public string DisplayData()
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofiles WHERE TravellerName=@f1"
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", User.Identity.Name)
    conn.Open()
    Dim profileDr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    profileDr.Read() 
  string imagename= profileDr("AvatarURL")   
    conn.Close()
return imagename

End Sub
```

and client side change for

```
<asp:Image ID="ProfilePic" **ImageUrl='<%# DisplayData()%>'** runat="server" />
```

Comment: Hi, this code isn't working for me. Are you sure there are no errors in it. It doesn't accept string at all and return is not allowed.